# Python functions and calling args

Tags: python, args

I'm creating my first python tool, if you want to call it that. (I work in IT Security, btw)

It was going well until I tried to call a function from the main function. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing :(. Could someone point me in the right direction? Then feel free to point and laugh.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, getopt, socket

def usage():
    print "-h --help: help\n"
    print "-f --file: File to read bruteforce domain list from.\n"
    print "-p --proxy: Proxy address and port. e.g http://192.168.1.64:8080\n"
    print "-d --domain: Domain to bruteforce.\n"
    print "-e: Turn debug on.\n"
    sys.exit()

def main(argv):
    file = None
    proxy = None
    domain = None
    try:
       opts, argv =getopt.getopt(argv, "h:f:p:d:e",["help", "file=", "proxy=", "domain="])

     except getopt.GetoptError as err:
       print str(err)
       usage()
       sys.exit(2)

     for opt, arg in opts:
       if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
       usage()
       sys.exit()
     elif opt in ("-f", "--file"):
       file = arg
     elif opt in ("-p", "--proxy"):
       proxy = arg
     elif opt in ("-d", "--domain"):
       domain = arg
     elif opt in '-e':
       global _debug
       _debug = 1
     else:
        assert Flase, "Unhandled option"
print fread.flist

def fread(file, *args):
   flist = open(file).readlines()
   return


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Show us the traceback.

Comment: Apologies forgot to add it `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'flist'`

Comment: The *whole* traceback, with line numbers and everything. (Matt's answer is correct, though.)

Comment: You should use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) for parsing arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your statement `print fread.flist`. You can't access variables assigned inside functions this way. Instead, change your `fread()` function to the following:

```
def fread(file, *args):
   flist = open(file).readlines()
   return flist
```

and change the statement above to

```
print fread(file)
```

where `file` is the file you want to access.

Comment: see told you would be damb simple lol. Im learning tho, getting there thanks for the help! really apprecaiated

Comment: no problem. BTW, I just caught this - in your `assert` line, it should be `False`, not `Flase` :)

Comment: lol thanks, can you answer a simple question please. I want to understand this. why do i call file in `print fread(file)` instead of `print fread(flist)` ?